# How do I install "Need for Speed World"?

Tags: 11.10, wine, games

How do I install Need for Speed World?

Please don't just say "use wine", I am a newbie and I need a detailed way to install it (Step by Step).

I use Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Download Game>Install Wine (Open a terminal, Click the Ubuntu Logo then type `Terminal` then type `sudo apt-get install wine1.3`)>Open up Wine>Try to install game>iF it fails then you're out of luck and won't be enjoying the game/if it succeds you still won't be able to play the game due to the fact that Anti-cheat software (because it's an online game...) probably wouldn't work in Linux.

Comment: Here is an explanation how to install by wine: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Need for Speed World can be run on Ubuntu, at least not without difficulties. It's designed specifically as a Windows application.

In some cases, you can still use Wine, but it's no guarantee. It is far beyond the scope of this site. However, wine itself has a community that is suitable for those types of things.

For Need for Speed World, you can [look here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20659&iTestingId=59988).

Comment: [This report](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20659&iTestingId=68020) says it works nicely in 11.10.

Comment: Well.. It says it sometimes works if you jump through a few hoops.

Comment: Yes, Need for Speed World can be run. On Ubuntu 22.04, PlayOnLinux does not work, so I found the alternative to solve the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut

Comment: @luisito_36: I wrote this on Newyears Day in  2012; that's almost 11 years ago. I think you should write a new answer. :)

Answer (score -3):

this doesn't work in Ubuntu because Ubuntu doesn't support the functions that the game need to work/run, and wine doesn't neither.... so there's only four things to do....
A) wait until need for speed world is supported by Ubuntu
B) switch to windows
C) run windows in virtual-box 
D) or don't play it any at all